# Why does my URL while using the CodeIgniter framework only work with a question mark in front of the directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following code for my .htaccess for the PHP framework CodeIgniter.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L]
```

If I type in the url http://linuxservers.org/articles  The articles page does not load (the index does).  However, if I type in linuxservers.org/?articles or /?/articles the page will load.  I don't get it.

In addition to that, if I change the last line in the code above to

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/?$1 [L]
```

OR

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [L]
```

(which redirects /articles to either /?articles or /?/articles, the page loads.
index.php/articles loads the page as well, which is the default format for CodeIgnitor.

Hopefully that made sense, if not, ask me questions.  Looking forward to your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get your `.htaccess` file from? The [one on the CodeIgniter wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) has the last line as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Which is one of your working options.

Comment: That "works" but the url shows up as /?/articles instead of just /articles

Comment: That redirects /articles to /?/articles  .  /?/articles will load the articles page without that line though.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the issue you were having. It's most likely related to using the `[L]` flag, have a look here: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/notes-last

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  That seems to be my problem.

Comment: Hey chad, I'm still having some trouble with this.  I got the index.php/articles to redirect to /articles but I'm not sure how to get the server to think that the page is index.php/articles because it doesn't want to load /articles unless I have /?articles still  Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that.. finally got it :)